# Sorting on GeoWithin MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, nosql

So I made this query:

> db.zips.find( { loc : { $geoWithin : { $box :[ [ -90 , 30 ] , [ -80 , 40 ] ] } } } )

And here is one (out of many) outputs:

{ "city" : "APISON", "loc" : [ -85.016404, 35.014926 ], "pop" : 1614, "state" : "TN", "_id" : "37302" }

My question is how would i be able to sort this by population and limit it to 10? When i try {$sort{pop:1}} i get errors it doesn't know pop, also when i add {$limit:10} at the end or my query it doesn't limit it to 10 entries but only shows me the last column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $sort and $limit are part of aggregation framework, not regular find command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.zips.find({loc:{$geoWithin:{$box:[[-90,30],[-80,40]]}}}).sort({pop:1}).limit(10)